# Postgres function to return multiple rows

Tags: postgresql

I have below function takes **showid** argument and returns one row of all data related to that **showid** from different tables into **movie** TYPE. I want to add another version of the function that takes no arguments, and returns details about all movies, each movie on a row into **movie** TYPE.

movie TYPE:

```
CREATE TYPE movie as (                                     
id BIGINT,
title TEXT,
year INT,
overview TEXT,
actors TEXT[],
directors TEXT[],
genres TEXT[]
);
```

---

Function movie_details:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION movie_details (movieid BIGINT)
RETURNS SETOF movie
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$

DECLARE
show SHOWS;
film FILMS;
movie_actors TEXT[];
movie_directors TEXT[];
movie_genres TEXT[];

BEGIN

SELECT * INTO show FROM shows s 
WHERE s.showid = movieid;

SELECT f.* INTO film FROM films F
JOIN shows s USING (showid)
WHERE s.showid = movieid; 

SELECT array_agg(concat_ws(' ', fname, mname, lname)) INTO movie_actors FROM people p
JOIN actin a USING (personid)
JOIN shows s USING (showid)
WHERE s.showid = movieid;

SELECT array_agg(concat_ws(' ', fname, mname, lname)) INTO movie_directors FROM people p
JOIN direct d USING (personid)
JOIN shows s USING (showid)
WHERE s.showid = movieid;

SELECT array_agg(g.name) INTO movie_genres from genres g
JOIN showgenres USING (genreid)
JOIN shows s USING (showid)
WHERE s.showid = movieid;

RETURN QUERY
SELECT show.showid, show.title, film.year, show.overview, movie_actors, movie_directors, movie_genres;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: With combination of https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/arrays.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-cursors.html it should be easy to accomplish what you need. First open a cursor, then populate multidimensional array with results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION movie_details () 
RETURNS SETOF movie
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$

DECLARE
show SHOWS;
film FILMS;
movie_actors TEXT[];
movie_directors TEXT[];
movie_genres TEXT[];
movieid BIGINT;
BEGIN
FOR movieid IN SELECT showid FROM shows
LOOP
SELECT * INTO show FROM shows s 
WHERE s.showid = movieid;

SELECT f.* INTO film FROM films f
JOIN shows s USING (showid)
WHERE s.showid = movieid; 

SELECT array_agg(concat_ws(' ', fname, mname, lname)) INTO movie_actors FROM people p
JOIN actin a USING (personid)
JOIN shows s USING (showid)
WHERE s.showid = movieid;

SELECT array_agg(concat_ws(' ', fname, mname, lname)) INTO movie_directors FROM people p
JOIN direct d USING (personid)
JOIN shows s USING (showid)
WHERE s.showid = movieid;

SELECT array_agg(g.name) INTO movie_genres from genres g
JOIN showgenres USING (genreid)
JOIN shows s USING (showid)
WHERE s.showid = movieid;
RETURN QUERY SELECT show.showid, show.title, film.year, show.overview, movie_actors, movie_directors, movie_genres;
END LOOP;
RETURN;
END;
$$;;
```